# How to re-render application template with new router?

Tags: ember.js

## The code

I'm using the version [4fcdbf2560](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/4fcdbf256039e8ca8d2647050e0c9a71234c922c) with the new router.

In my application, a user can be authenticated or not. The rendered template will not be the same depending on the authentication state.

I've manage this by redefining the function `renderTemplate` in the `ApplicationRoute`:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render(App.authenticated() ? 'authenticated' : 'unauthenticated');
    }
});
```

My router is quite simple:

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
    match('/').to('index');

    match('/sign').to('sign', function(match) {
        match('/in').to('signIn');
    });

    match('/dashboard').to('dashboard');
});
```

The `IndexRoute` is just here to redirect the user depending on the authentication state:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo(App.authenticated() ? 'dashboard' : 'signIn');
    }
});
```

## The workflow

1. A user navigates to `/`
2. The `ApplicationRoute` is entered, as the user is not authenticated, the `unauthenticated` template is rendered
3. The `IndexRoute` is entered, as the user is not authenticated, a redirection is made to `signIn`
4. The `signIn` template is rendered into its parent template -> the `unauthenticated` template
5. The user sign in successfully, `route.transitionTo('dashboard')` is called
6. The `dashboard` template is rendered into its parent template -> the `unauthenticated` template

## The questions

- What's wrong with my implementation ?
- Why does the `renderTemplate` function is not called when the `dashboard` template is rendered ?
- How can I force the application to re-render its template ?

## Edit 2013-01-07

I've modified my code according to Evan's answer.

My application template now looks like this:

```
{{#if isAuthenticated}}
    <h1>Authenticated</h1>
    {{outlet}}
{{else}}
    <h1>Unauthenticated</h1>
    {{outlet}}
{{/if}}
```

When the user lands on the application page, as he's not authenticated, it's the unauthenticated block which is rendered. Everything is working well except that nothing render into the `{{outlet}}` tag...

But when my application template looks like this (=without conditional tags):

```
<h1>Unauthenticated</h1>
{{outlet}}
```

...it works ! So I wonder if the `{{outlet}}` tag can be inserted between conditional tags.

Comment: for outlet inside blocks: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1671, I hope for you this will be merged ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be a mistake to have this logic in the Router; Instead this should be part of the ApplicationController.

Since ember will automatically update the templates as application state changes you can create an ApplicationController that tracks the authentication state

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isAuthenticated: null
});
```

And construct your templates like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{ #if isAuthenticated }}
        You are now logged in
    {{ else }}
        Please Log In
    {{ /if }}
</script>
```

Now you don't actually have to worry about manually updating / rendering the template. As the internal (JS) state changes your template will automatically update to reflect the application state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question to add more informations.

Answer (score 2):

[sly7_7 comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185040/how-to-re-render-application-template-with-new-router/#comment-19698380) is the answer. See [github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1671](http://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1671) for outlet inside blocks.

This has just been merged into master: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1671#issuecomment-11982451

Comment: Can you verify this works for your question with the latest master ? I this is right, I think you can accept your answer, or Evan's one

Comment: Nice ! I will check that in the comming hours and let you know.

Comment: Great :), indeed I think it's a pretty neat way to manage authent :)