# How can you store a path and transitionTo it later in Ember's v2 Router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

i'm trying to migrate to the new Router in Ember.  the use case is this: user is not logged in but requests a URL that requires login.  he is redirected to a login route, after successful login he is redirected to his original destination.

i achieved this with the prior Router by overriding Router.route(path) and intercepting path requests when the app was in unauthorized state.

the new Router doesn't have a route() function, also, i don't know how to override it now that the Router instance is created automatically by Ember.  i probably shouldn't do that anyway.

there is a Route.redirect() hook that looks useful.  however, Route no longer extends Path in the v2 Router, so there is no Root.path, and no path information is passed into Route.redirect(), so i don't know how to save the path info for calling transitionTo() later.

i've supplied my general approach below.  how can i accomplish this?  it seems like a very common use case for many application.

```
  // i imagine something like this should happen
  App.AuthRequiredRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
       redirect: function() {
            if(!App.controllerFor('login').get('isLoggedIn')) {
                  var pathToSave = ????
                  App.controllerFor('login').set('pathAfterLogin',pathToSave);
                  this.transitionTo('login');
             }
        }
   }
   // and then after login, the LoginController would call App.router.transitionTo(this.pathAfterLogin)
```

Comment: i should add that when answering this, keep in mind that dynamic segments need to be supported too.

Comment: I'm trying to do authentication related work with the new router like you. I don't have an answer for you, sorry :(. But maybe you will have one for me ? ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185040/how-to-re-render-application-template-with-new-router

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lot of research into this myself in the last day or two. I can share with you what I have discovered, and a couple of thoughts.

First of all, you can some information regarding the current path and contexts like so:

```
this.router.router.currentHandlerInfos
```

This returns an array. Each object has both a name and a context property. The names correspond to the name of the router you would call in transitionTo.

In my opinion, although you could work with something like this, it would be messy. The API docs don't refer to this and it may not be the intention to use this as a public API.

I see issues with the above solution for deeper nested dynamic segments too. Given how new the router v2 is, I think it will continue to evolve and a better solution is likely to present itself. It's a fairly common thing to want to save the current location and return to it at a later date.

In the meantime, rather than a redirect, perhaps use a conditional block in your template that presents a login rather than an outlet if the authenticated flag is not set on the ApplicationController? I know it's not as "right" but it is "right now".